# Order subquery with order by

Tags: mysql

I need order my query for my subquery field.

Attempt:

```
 SELECT * from
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM (`multicategoria`)
    INNER JOIN `modelo` ON `modelo`.`id_MOD` = `multicategoria`.`id_MOD`
    INNER JOIN `categoria` ON `categoria`.`id_CAT` = `multicategoria`.`id_CAT`
    LEFT JOIN `media` ON `media`.`id_MED` = `modelo`.`id_MED`
    WHERE `categoria`.`id_CAT` =  '154'
    LIMIT 20, 4 )
order by x.id_CAT
```

But mysql output:

> (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

What is `x`?  The missing alias on the subquery?

Get rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ...
    JOIN ...  ON ...
    JOIN ...  ON ...
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY ...   -- Belongs after WHERE and before LIMIT
    LIMIT ...;     -- Useless without ORDER BY
```

Problem:  Since you are specifying a single value for `id_CAT`, it does not make sense to `ORDER BY id_CAT`.  Perhaps you want to `ORDER BY id_CAT, something_else`?  Or simply  `ORDER BY something_else`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to name the inner table:

```
SELECT * 
from ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (multicategoria) 
    INNER JOIN modelo ON modelo.id_MOD = multicategoria.id_MOD 
    INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_CAT = multicategoria.id_CAT 
    LEFT JOIN media ON media.id_MED = modelo.id_MED 
    WHERE categoria.id_CAT = '154' LIMIT 20, 4 ) 
as TABLE_ALIAS  order by x.id_CAT;
```

Comment: MYSQL output : Duplicate column name 'id_MOD'

Comment: change * for list of columns, with table name prefix . Also next error will be unknown table x - change it for real alias

Comment: Or just remove the derived table and use `... ORDER BY table_name.id_CAT LIMIT 20,4 ;`